# Having audio and playback issues when attempting to capture DVCPro50 tapes over Firewire with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-encoding

I've been trying to capture DVCPro50 tapes that were recorded at 23.976 fps over Firewire and I'm unable to come up with a command to get the file to play back properly. I can get a file with audio at 29.97 fps; a file with no audio at 23.976; and I can successfully capture the video/audio at the correct framerate with QuickTime Player 10, but I need to be able to save the files as native DV video (wrapped in MXF).

Here are some of the commands I've been trying:

I'm getting the correct specs using this command:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -drop_late_frames 0 -capture_raw_data 1 -i 1 -f mxf -map 0:0 -c copy -r 24000/1001 test.mxf
```

...but the file is silent. There are four channels of 16/48 audio in the file, but nothing in those.

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -drop_late_frames 0 -capture_raw_data 1 -i 1 -f rawvideo -map 0 -c copy test.mxf
```

Gives me a file with pic/sound, but playing back in hyper speed ( seems about 1.25x, which would be the approximate difference between 30p and 24p ).

When I run: `ffprobe -f avfoundation -i AJ-HD1400`, I get:

> Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 704x480, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1000k tbn

Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: Question 1: Why do you use `-map 0:0` in your first command? It maps only the first stream from the first input so it's nothing strange that all audio streams could be missing. `-map 0` would map all streams (just like in your second command). Question 2: Why do you define the output's framerate in the first command (`-r 24000/1001`) but not in your second one?